# OSError when attempting to close a socket

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a very simple server that receives a connection, tests to see if the data is "HelloClient", if it is it sends back "HelloServer", if it isn't it closes the connection.  However, when it gets any response it throws an error

`OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`

Searching for the error didn't yield any fruit, what is causing this and how do I fix it?

Code reference:

```
class ClientHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    state = 0

    def handle(self):
        print(self.client_address)
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            print("Received: ", data, " from ", self.client_address)    # MARKER
            self.parse(data)
        self.request.close()

    def parse(self, data):
        if self.state == 0:
            if data == b"HelloClient":
                self.state = 1
                self.request.send(b"HelloServer")
            else:
                self.request.close()  #PROBLEM LINE

host = ''  
port = 50007  
addr = (self.myHost, self.myPort)
socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(addr, ClientHandler).serve_forever()
```

Comment: is you server handling client close() request correctly ? can you share server code too

Comment: This is the server code (well, technically I guess the heavy lifting is ThreadingTCPServer, I'm just writing the handler for now).  I'm not sure what you mean about client close() - when the self.request.close() line executes, the socket is still open and its still listening (because the client can send another message).  Hope this helps clarify?

Comment: Well, **you** close the socket in `parse`, return in your loop and try to read from the just closed socket. That is the cause of the error. Anyway, a handler is not expected to close anything, the client should close. What are you trying to achieve here?